# Convert IP list to minimal CIDR representation

Tags: ip

I have a list of IP addresses that looks like this:

```
10.10.0.0
10.10.0.1
10.10.0.2
...
10.10.0.255
172.171.0.5
...
172.171.0.67
```

Is there a tool that can take such a list and compute the minimal CIDR representation for these IP addresses?

For instance, for the above example I would like to get the following output:

```
10.10.0.0/24
172.171.0.5/32
172.171.0.6/31
172.171.0.8/29
172.171.0.16/28
172.171.0.32/27
172.171.0.64/30
```

Edit: for clarification, the "minimal CIDR representation" would be the smallest set of CIDR IP addresses that contains all the IP addresses of my input file.

Comment: Why is the mask `/24` for `10.10.0.0` in your output? The list in your expected output does not correspond to your example input.

Comment: The `...` meant that the list of IP continues so the first block of the list goes from `10.10.0.0` to `10.10.0.255`. Likewise, the second range that appears goes from `172.171.0.5` to `172.171.0.67`. Sorry if it was not clear

Comment: Could you possibly explain what "minimal CIDR representation" is, or alternatively request that this question be migrated to a more suitable site where networking is the main topic?

Comment: @Kusalananda I wrote to you elsewhere "really 10.0.0.0/24" but I meant "10.10.0.0/24" as written by OP sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Kusalananda basically I would like to convert my IP addresses into CIDR form with the less possible lines in the output. In my above example, my input file contains all IP addresses of the range `10.10.0.0-10.10.0.255`, hence I should have `10.10.0.0/24` in my output. But say that in the input file I also have all the the IP from the range `10.10.1.0-10.10.1.255`, then I would like to have `10.10.0.0/23` in my output

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708272/list-of-ip-addresses-in-python-to-a-list-of-cidr

Comment: @rubytox This is not clear from the question. Please update the question with further clarifications.

Comment: For reference, here is a useful resource https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#IPv4_CIDR_blocks

Answer (score 1):

Using the builtin python module [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) suggested by @A.B in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708272/list-of-ip-addresses-in-python-to-a-list-of-cidr) suggesting this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708272/list-of-ip-addresses-in-python-to-a-list-of-cidr).

Either [summarize_address_range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.summarize_address_range) (with start, end) or [collapse_addresses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.collapse_addresses) (with a list) can be used.

For this case, the latter is more convenient.

```py
import sys
import ipaddress

data = open(sys.argv[1],'r').read().splitlines()
ips = [ipaddress.IPv4Address(line) for line in data]
print('\n'.join([ip.with_prefixlen for ip in ipaddress.collapse_addresses(ips)]))
```

Usage and output:

```
$ python3 cidr.py file
10.10.0.0/24
172.171.0.5/32
172.171.0.6/31
172.171.0.8/29
172.171.0.16/28
172.171.0.32/27
172.171.0.64/30
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a problem I've been interested in solving for a while and you can do this with the `ipaddress` module however my implementation is probably needlessly complicated, however it does work:

```
from ipaddress import IPv4Address, IPv6Address, IPv4Network, IPv6Network
addrs = ["10.10.0.0", "10.10.0.1", "10.10.0.2", "10.10.0.255", "172.171.0.5", "172.171.0.67"]
out = []
while True:
    if len(addrs) == 0:
        break
    found = False
    for index in out:
        if IPv4Network(addrs[0], 32).subnet_of(index.supernet(new_prefix=8)):
            cur = index
            while True:
                if cur.supernet_of(IPv4Network(addrs[0], 32)):
                    break
                else:
                    cur = cur.supernet()
            out[out.index(index)] = cur
            addrs.pop(0)
            found = True
            break
    if not found:
        out.append(IPv4Network(addrs.pop(0), 32).supernet())
```

this will give you the following result:

```
In [81]: out
Out[81]: [IPv4Network('10.10.0.0/24'), IPv4Network('172.171.0.0/25')]
```

I'm not 100% sold on my own implementation but I think this could be done better, this will also only coalesce up to a `/8`. This at least should give you some idea of how to work with the ipaddress module and what you can do with it.